# QFT - Confusion with the provided solution of a problem in Student Friendly Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, field-theory

I was going through the solution (provided by the author of the book R.D. Klauber) of Problem 14, Chapter 6 in the link -  http://www.quantumfieldtheory.info/Correction_Ch06_prob_14.pdf
on Klauber's website - http://www.quantumfieldtheory.info/corrections_to_solutions.htm and I am confused with a step which I think may be wrong. Any help either confirming the author's error or pointing out any conceptual error on my part will be much appreciated -

If I compare the first equation highlighted with yellow (equation A) - 
$$
\int \varphi^\dagger_{,\mu}\varphi^{,\mu}dV=
\sum_k \frac{-k_\mu k^\mu}{2\omega_k}(e^{-2i\omega_k t}b(\boldsymbol{k})a(\boldsymbol{-k})
-b(\boldsymbol{k})b^\dagger(\boldsymbol{k})-a^\dagger(\boldsymbol{k})a(\boldsymbol{k})+
e^{2i\omega_k t}a^\dagger(\boldsymbol{k})b^\dagger(\boldsymbol{-k})
$$

with the last equation just before the first equation highlighted with yellow, he seems to have substituted $k^{"\mu}$ in one line with $k^\mu$ in the next line. I mean the $k^{"\mu}$ and $k^\mu$ that appear just after the summations over $k$ and $k"$ and before the first bracket on the R.H.S of both equations.  I don't think this is correct because this is only possible in the case where $k_i$ = $k"_i$ and not for the case where $k_i$ = - $k"_i$ , the time components of $k$ and $k"$ being equal to each other in both cases. I think therefore the single summation in the yellow highlighted line should actually split into two summations - one over the sub-terms without exponents and another over the sub-terms with the exponential factors. So according to me the correct form of the R.H.S of equation (A) should be :

${\sum\limits_{k}}$ $-\frac{k_\mu k^\mu}{2\omega_k}$$(-b(k)b^\dagger(k)$ - $a^\dagger(k)a(k))$ + ${\sum\limits_{k}}$ -(${k_0k^0 -k_1k^1-k_2k^2-k_3k^3})$$(e^{-2i\omega_kt}b(k)a(-k) + e^{2i\omega_kt}a^\dagger(k)b^\dagger(-k))$

I do not think this affects the final answer that the Lagrangian is invariant under the said transform, however I felt the need to ask and clarify my point. As I am not completely convinced of my step either any pointers as to whether I am right or wrong will be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had written to Robert Klauber about the error. He has responded confirming the error and has corrected it. The corrections are available at the same two links I had mentioned in my question, i.e,
http://www.quantumfieldtheory.info/Correction_Ch06_prob_14.pdf   and   http://www.quantumfieldtheory.info/corrections_to_solutions.htm

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. For the first term $k_\mu k"^\mu$ should give $\omega^2 +|\vec k|^2$ in disagreement with the result shown.

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment, especially given you have sufficient reputation to post as a comment.